# password protect apache user directory using system passwords

Tags: apache-2.2, password, httpd

I have set up Apache to check user passwords using these modules:

```
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
```

However, these modules require me to manually add everyone to a new password file (which requires every user to type in their password).

Is there a way to have Apache check the system passwords, so that anyone who can ssh can use the same password for web login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mod-auth-external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) plus [pwauth](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/).

Answer (score 1):

We used [mod_auth_pam](http://pam.sourceforge.net/mod_auth_pam/index.html) in the past, but that's kind of old now and it looks like they recommend [mod_auth_external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) now.  The latter looks like its been updated in the recent past.  Here's their HOWTOs: http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/w/list